# Python SMTP Not Working For Me - Mail Not Sent Empty Dictionary Returned

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to send mail via Python's smtplib module.

I found a couple of examples online but none of them have worked so far. I am able to connect to the SMTP server with no authentication as this server does not use a password. However, when I use the `sendmail` method the mail is not sent to me and an empty dictionary is returned to the interactive Python shell.

I do not have direct access to the SMTP server logs to try and debug this, but maybe able to get some help with this.

The screenshot that follows points out areas of interest/concern. Also, I copy and pasted the text from the Python interactive shell for you and your screen-reader, which could be quite handy and fun.

I changed some of the names like my e-mail address and the exact name of the mail server. I do not actually work at job.com if that is a domain or business. Thanks for reading this. I am very skeptical this will be solved! :/

[image: screen shot of python 2.7 smtp trouble]

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import smtplib
>>> SERVER = smtplib.SMTP()
>>> SERVER.connect('mail.devexchange.local')
(220, 'interzone.devexchange.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mo                                             n, 4 Jun 2018 19:58:21 -0500')
>>> help(SERVER)

>>> SERVER.help()
'This server supports the following commands:\nHELO EHLO STARTTLS RCPT DATA RSET                                              MAIL QUIT HELP AUTH BDAT'
>>> help(SERVER)

>>> SERVER.getreply()



(451, '4.7.0 Timeout waiting for client input')
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> SERVER.send('me@me.com', 'myemail@job.com', 'hello from smtp')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: send() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
>>> SERVER.sendmail('me@me.com', 'myemail@job.com', 'hello from smtp')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 722, in sendmail
    self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 541, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
    if not (200 <= self.ehlo()[0] <= 299):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 412, in ehlo
    self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 340, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 330, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('Server not connected')
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Server not connected
>>> SERVER.connect('mail.devexchange.local')
(220, 'interzone.devexchange.local Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mo                                             n, 4 Jun 2018 20:13:18 -0500')
>>> SERVER.sendmail('me@me.com', 'myemail@job.com', 'hello from smtp')
{}
>>>
```

**UPDATE** - Looks like my office is filtering this and not letting the e-mail be sent. I suppose the code is great, just not my organization's security policy. :/

Comment: The docs say it returns normally if all is fine, or throws an exception if an error occurs.https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail

Comment: One thing to consider is if your recipient is allowed to receive external emails. If your network does not allow emails from me@me.com, it will show up in the SMTP logs.

Comment: I think me@me.com is the `from` field of the e-mail... As far as network filtering out the e-mail that is something else to consider. Any way to know if the network is filtering and what it is filtering other than asking sysadmins?

Comment: @dfundako Returning normally usually is returning nothing I would think instead of returning an empty dictionary. Although, I do not know what this method normally does. I was surprised by the empty dictionary returned. Seems like some sort of error. I want to send an e-mail but instead receive these useless handle bars. :/

Comment: @dfundako You are correct. This method does return a dictionary when an exception is not thrown. Thank-you for the link to the documentation. From the docs, "If this method does not raise an exception, it returns a dictionary,". :)